# How to Call the Column Index Number in Vlookup : VBA

Tags: vba, excel

How to call the column index no `d` in vlookup. `"=vlookup(RC[-15],"& Rg.Address(True, True, xlR1C1, xlExternal) & ",d,False)"` is it correct?. refer below code (note Vlookup using with one workbook to another workbook)

```
Sub Vlkuprangcall()
Dim strColumn As String
Dim Rg As Range
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim d, a, Lastrow As Long

Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ashokkumar.d\Desktop\Test\IC Raphael\Janalakshmi\MIS\MIS.xlsx")
Set Rg = wb2.Sheets(3).Range("A3:Z10000")
d = 6
Application.Workbooks(2).Activate
With ActiveSheet
    a = ActiveCell.Column
    Lastrow = 100
    strColumn = Split(ActiveCell.Address, "$")(1)
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=vlookup(RC[-15],"& Rg.Address(True, True, xlR1C1, xlExternal) & ",d,False)"
    ActiveCell.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell, Range(strColumn & Lastrow))
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take out the `d` variable outside the `"`.

Replace your `FormulaR1C1` line :

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=vlookup(RC[-15],"& Rg.Address(True, True, xlR1C1, xlExternal) & ",d,False)"
```

With :

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=vlookup(RC[-15]," & Rg.Address(True, True, xlR1C1, xlExternal) & "," & d & ",False)"
```

**Note**: Defining `Dim d, a, Lastrow As Long` , means only `Lastrow As Long` , while `d` and `a` will be defined as `Variant`.

Change this line to `Dim d As Long, a As Long, Lastrow As Long`